# How to allow text quotes in html-sanitizer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, html-sanitizing

I am using [html-sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package//sanitize-html) to clean html and prevent xcss ijection although I am facing a problem.
When a user types a caracter such as `&, >, <, ""` it gets converted to their equivalent HTML character references (`& --> &amp;, < --> &lt;`, and so on).

Here's my code sample it's very simple I need to allow those caracters and i couldn't find a way to do so:

```
let clean = sanitizeHtml(req.body.content, {
        allowedAttributes: {
        
          span: ["data-*", "class"],
        },
      });
```

Can anyone provide help or insights?

Comment: I can't think of any reasons where you would need to allow the raw versions of those characters where it wouldn't be completely inappropriate to be using sanitize-html in the first place. This feels like it is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Do you think i should allow them to be converted and then parse them back to their original caracters ?I am actually trying to find a solution . i store them in the db in their raw format but when i display them in the front-end they stay like that . @Quentin

Comment: See [my previous link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't know what the actual problem you are trying to solve is. You need to provide a lot more context.

Comment: @Quentin I need to configure the sanitizer to not convert those caracters . That's my problem

Comment: Unlikely. As I said before, "configure the sanitizer to not convert those caracters" appears to be your attempt to solve the real problem. It is unlikely to be a good way to solve the real problem. You haven't told us what the real problem is.

Comment: "i store them in the db in their raw format" — The fact your are passing `req.body.content` to `sanitizeHtml` suggests you are encoding them as HTML as soon as they come into your backend and then storing the HTML encoded (not the raw) data in the database.

Comment: We're using quill in the front end so i receive HTML content . I am using the sanitizer to prevent injection but I need to keep the text . for exemple if a user types  " Hello & Hello " as a title it gets converted to "Hello &amp Hello" which gets displayed after instead of the original text he typed. For user experience purposes I need to allow those caracters

Comment: Quill is a tool for generating HTML. html-sanitizer is a tool for processing **plain text** for insertion into HTML. html-sanitizer is not suitable for use when you already have HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248477/discussion-between-nermineslimane-and-quentin).

Comment: I don't think there's anything else to say, unless you are planning to ask me to recommend a tool for sanitising HTML input for XSS which I can't provide as I've never needed to solve that problem in Node and have no idea what libraries are available for that.

Comment: Doesn't quill already sanitize the html that it's generating to prevent script injecting etc?